Show that $3\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2x}}-1+2\sqrt{2x}-2\sqrt{2x+1-\sqrt{2x}}$ is nonnegative over $x\in[0, 1/8]$
Consider the function $f(x)=3\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2x}}-1+2\sqrt{2x}-2\sqrt{2x+1-\sqrt{2x}}$ where $x\in[0, 1/8]$.
I want to show that $f(x)\geq0$.
By substituting for $x=0$ and $x=1/8$, I get $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/8)\approx0.3$.
Using these endpoints, my usual strategy for this type of problem would then be to show that $f(x)$ is monotonic.
However, by plotting this function, I can see that it is concave and positive for all $x\leq 0.36$.
I am not sure how best to approach this to show this result analytically.

What happens when you compute the derivatives $~f'(x)~$ and (if necessary) $~f''(x)? ~$ Can you use these computation(s) to explore the behavior of $~f(x)~?~$  While this approach might not solve the problem, it would automatically be my first try.

Re previous comment, for such a problem, the standard way of avoiding having to calculate $~f''(x)~$ is to (also) compute $~f(x)~$ at the endpoints of the interval, and [depending on the computation of $~f'(x)~$] perhaps other values for $~x,~$ as well.

@user2661923 I have looked at $f'(x)$, but $f''(x)$ is relatively complex. I've also looked at $f(x)$ at the endpoints, as stated in the question. Do you mean that I should look at $f'(x)$ at the endpoints as well?

No.  I mean that you should try to determine how many times, in the interval that $~f'(x) = 0.~$ If (for example) it happens exactly once, then it is sufficient to also examine $~f(x)~$ at the end points.  If $~f'(x) = 0~$ for more than one value of $~x,~$ in the interval, then I suggest, for each $~x_1, ~x_2~$ such that $f'(x_1) = 0 = f'(x_2),~$ also choose some convenient value $~x_3~$ such that $~x_1 < x_3 < x_2,~$ and examine $~f(x_3).$

Re my last comment, if (for example) $~f'(x)~$ is never equal to $~0~$ in the interval, then it is sufficient to (merely) also look at $~f(x)~$ at the endpoints.

you may   say $x = \frac{u^2}{2}$   with $0 \leq u \leq \frac{1}{2}$

If you want to do it in an elementary way, you can proceed as follows:
Set $\boxed{u^2=1-\sqrt{2x}}$.Hence, $u\in [\sqrt 2/2,1]$ and $\sqrt{2x}=1-u^2$. You get:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}g(u) = f(x(u)) & = & 3u-(u^2-(1-u^2))-2\sqrt{u^2+(1-u^2)^2} \\
& = & 3u-2u^2+1 - 2\sqrt{1-{\color{blue}{u^2}}+u^4} \\
&\stackrel{u\in [\sqrt 2/2,1]}{\geq } & 3u-2u^2+1 - 2\sqrt{1-{\color{blue}{u^4}}+u^4} \\
& = & 3u-2u^2-1 \\
& = & -(2u-1)(u-1) \\
& \geq & 0 \text{ on } [1/2,1] \supset [\sqrt 2/2,1]
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Thank you very much for this clear and concise answer. It is most appreciated.

I wonder if you might have a tip for a related question: show that $g(x)=\bigg[\frac{1}{3}\bigg(1-2\sqrt{2x}+2\sqrt{2x+1-\sqrt{2x}}\bigg)\bigg]^3+2\sqrt{2x}+1-2\sqrt{2x+1-\sqrt{2x}}-3x\geq0$ for $x\in[0, 1/8]$ again.  Would you suggest trying a similar approach to your answer? This is another concave function, with the maximum attained before $x=1/8$.

@Hal_Incandenza
I would definitely try a similar approach for your second problem. But, at first glance, it looks nastier. Main goal is to get rid of as many roots a possible, even if you use other techniques like derivatives later.

I've given this a shot now. With the substitution $u^2=1-\sqrt{2x}$, I obtain
\begin{equation*}
\bigg[\frac{1}{3}\bigg(2u^2-1+2\sqrt{1-u^2+u^4} \bigg)\bigg]^3 +3-2u^2-2\sqrt{1-u^2+u^4}-\frac{3}{2}\bigg(1-u^2\bigg)^2.
\end{equation*}
However, using the same trick as in your answer (replacing $-u^2$ with $-u^4$ in the remaining square roots), I get
\begin{equation*}
0>\bigg[\frac{1}{3}\bigg(2u^2+1\bigg)\bigg]^3+1-2u^2-\frac{3}{2}\bigg(1-u^2\bigg)^2,
\end{equation*}
which I can't use to prove that $h(u)=g(x(u))\geq0$.

I would suggest to ask a new question with the new function instead of dealing with it in a comment section.
